# Getting attribute error when using AUTOTUNE in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using AUTOTUNE for audio processing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
```

But i am getting attribute error which said "module 'tensorflow._api.v2.data' has no attribute 'AUTOTUNE'". Tensorflow version is 2.3.0. How to solve this?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're expecting `AUTOTUNE` to do, as it seems to be used for automatic data pipelining for performance reasons.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [TensorFlow 2.3 documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental#other_members), `AUTOTUNE` lies under the `tensorflow.data.experimental` namespace. So using

```py
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
```

should avoid this error.

Answer (score 2):

With TF 2.3, Autotune was experimental and was in nightly build but in TF 2.5, it is in packages. We can do this if we want to train the model in TF 2.5 or TF 2.3.

```
try:
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE     
except:
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
```

Answer (score 0):

At least TF 2.4 you should install.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your TensorFlow using following comment

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```