# Error when calling AUTOTUNE from tensorflow version 2.9.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am using AUTOTUNE in my TensorFlow project for a long time ago. The project is in google colab. It runs fine in the past. Now when I try to run the project, it has an error. I think the tensorflow version is changed causing the error.

In the AUTOTUNE line it shows me:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.data.experimental' has no attribute 'AUTOTUNE'

I already try to implement the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962099/getting-attribute-error-when-using-autotune-in-tensorflow) but the issue is still there.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE     
except:
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
```

When I try to print the **TensorFlow version** and **tf.data.AUTOTUNE**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__, ',')
print(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

it show me the below result:

```
2.9.2 ,
-1
```

Need your help, please.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of this: import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__, ','); print(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

Comment: @jkr, question updated please

Comment: ok - seems like you can use `AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE` directly. no need for `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`. but something in that line is causing an error apparently... though I don't know what it would be.

Comment: I don't know why but after ``print(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`` now it is working. But before ``tf.data.AUTOTUNE`` itself is not working. I tried ``tf.data.AUTOTUNE`` but it is not working, then I tried ``tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`` and it is not working also. Finally, I tried the code that I got from the thread mentioned above, and still not working. Now I came back to the tf.data.AUTOTUNE it is working. Very strange.